# Android studio cannot resolve a symbol

Tags: android, android-mapview

[image: IMG]

Can anyone tell me why i am getting this "cannot resolve symbol "api" error "When i have included all the libraries in libs folder and also done changes in my build.gradle file as you can see in the pic below

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 0):

Go To file and click on Invalidate Caches/Restart .This fixed it for me.

Comment: import com.google.api.client.util.Key; error on "key " as android studio cannot resolve it has also been introduced after this step apart from the previous errord

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I cannot view the pictures. Did you enter your key in android manifest and have all required libraries installed?